# Return only one attribute in a mongodb query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

```
@Query("{'recibido' : null ,'activo' : true}")
public List<Long> findEmpleadosPrlActivoRecibidoIsNull();
```

I want you to return a list with the "employee_id" attribute of each object and not the whole object.

Can somebody help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a DTO that has an attribute with the same name that you want it to return

```
@Query("{'recibido' : null ,'activo' : true}")
public List<EmpleadoIdDTO> findIdsEmpleadosPrlActivoRecibidoIsNull();

public class EmpleadoIdDTO {
 private Long empleadoId;

 public Long getEmpleadoId() {
   return empleadoId;
 }

 public void setEmpleadoId(Long empleadoId) {
   this.empleadoId = empleadoId;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify [projection](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html) to select specific fields in result.

If you want to return only `employee_id`, your query will look like this:

```
db.collection.find({}, {employee_id:1, _id:0})
```

In Java API sepcified in doc above it will be:

```
collection.find().projection(fields(include("employee_id"), excludeId()))
```

Comment: And how do I put it in @Query?